# Wikidata: Get all living musicians with certain birth date

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to query wikidata to find musicians that share the same birthday, for example as in this snippet where these people share the same birthday (2nd April) and were born after 1900

```
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT distinct ?name (year(?date) as ?year)  WHERE {   
    ?entityS wdt:P569 ?date .
    ?entityS wdt:P1477 ?name.
    FILTER (datatype(?date) = xsd:dateTime) 
    FILTER (month(?date) = 4) # date
    FILTER (day(?date) = 2) # month
    FILTER (?date > "1900-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)
}
```

([run](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20distinct%20%3Fname%20%28year%28%3Fdate%29%20as%20%3Fyear%29%20%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%3FentityS%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3FentityS%20wdt%3AP1477%20%3Fname.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28datatype%28%3Fdate%29%20%3D%20xsd%3AdateTime%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28month%28%3Fdate%29%20%3D%204%29%20%23%20date%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28day%28%3Fdate%29%20%3D%202%29%20%23%20month%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fdate%20%3E%20%221900-01-01%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%0A%20%7D%20))

I want to filter by occupation musician i.e. `?professions {wd:Q177220 wd:Q639669}` however I am not having much success in applying this filter.

I have tried specifying `VALUES ?professions {wd:Q177220 wd:Q639669}`, to no effect.

Comment: what means "no effect"? Does this not work: `SELECT distinct ?name (year(?date) as ?year)  WHERE {   
    VALUES ?professions {wd:Q177220 wd:Q639669}
    ?entityS wdt:P569 ?date .
    ?entityS wdt:P1477 ?name.
    ?entityS wdt:P106 ?professions
    FILTER (datatype(?date) = xsd:dateTime) 
    FILTER (month(?date) = 4) # date
    FILTER (day(?date) = 2) # month
    FILTER (?date > "1900-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)
 } `

Comment: @UninformedUser consider add your comment as an answer. Also, I wonder if *instead of filtering by day and month*, why not set the filter as follows: `FILTER (?date > "1900-04-02"^^xsd:dateTime)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT distinct ?name (year(?date) as ?year) WHERE {
    VALUES ?professions {wd:Q177220 wd:Q639669}
       ?entityS wdt:P569 ?date .
       ?entityS wdt:P1477 ?name.
       ?entityS wdt:P106 ?professions     
    FILTER (datatype(?date) = xsd:dateTime)
    FILTER (month(?date) = 4) # date
    FILTER (day(?date) = 2) # month
    FILTER (?date > "1900-01-01"^^xsd:dateTime)  
}
```